# Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document<any>'

Tags: typescript, mongoose, model, properties, document

I am creating a User Schema in Mongoose using TypeScript, and when I'm referring to the properties of the Schema, like, *this.password*, I get this error:
**Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document'**
This error does not happen when I am using the properties on the pre() function because I can type it with my IUser interface. I can't do the same for my methods, so is there any way to fix this?? It's weird because I find other people using the same code and it works for them, so maybe the error comes from another thing. Here you can find the repository with the error: https://github.com/FaztWeb/restapi-jwt-ts

```
import { model, Schema, Document } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  comparePassword: (password: string) => Promise<Boolean>
};

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

userSchema.pre<IUser>("save", async function(next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
  user.password = hash;
  next();
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function(password: string): Promise<Boolean> {
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

export default model<IUser>("User", userSchema);
```

[OUTPUT ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBd37.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a generic declaration where you first create the `Schema`:

```
const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>({ ... });
```

That should make it such that `this` is refined to include `IUser` when you go to add the methods.