# Property 'password' does not exist on type Document<any>

Tags: typescript

I am getting this error Property in "UserSchema.methods.comparePassword" ->  **this.password**

Can anyone tell if there is something wrong with my code ?

```
import { model, Schema, Document } from 'mongoose'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

export interface IUser extends Document{
    email: String,
    password: String,
    comparePassword: (password: string) => Promise<Boolean>
};

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

UserSchema.pre<IUser>('save', async function(next) {
    if(!this.isModified('password')) return next();
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    next();
})

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (password: string): Promise<boolean>{

    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
}

export default model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Mongoose now accepts a generic prop on the `Schema` so you should call it like this `new Schema<IUser>({`.  You also need to replace the `String` and `Boolean` types in `IUser` with their lowercase versions. https://tsplay.dev/vwjA1W

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document<any>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974131/property-password-does-not-exist-on-type-documentany)